# Is there a list of all airways?

Tags: navigation, aeronautical-charts, flight-path, airways

Is there a public and current (AIRAC-cycle 1509)  **list** of all worldwide victor- and jetairways (including the pertaining intersections)? I'm not searching for a graphical map of the airways, but more for a text file listing all items.

---

*Sorry for the poor tagging, I couldn't find any suitable tag (there isn't one for "airway" or "intersections").*

Comment: This is something that you can probably purchase from a supplier of air navigation data such as Jeppesen or Lufthansa, but I don't know of a free world-wide source.  The FAA also sells this type of data, but it is for the US (and other aeronautical agencies around the world probably do as well.)

Comment: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16171/what-is-a-navigational-fix-where-can-i-get-navigational-fixes-for-a-local-airpo/16174#16174 at the bottom of this answer there is a short paragrph about navigational resources. maybe that helps.

Comment: There is an FAA publication that I found several weeks ago (while looking for something else, of course!) that seems to be freely available and contains this sort of data for the US.  It's published on a cycle, and when I get back to my other computer I'll see if I can dig up the link.  The data is only for the USA, though, so it's a very incomplete answer to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Airway data is published in each country by their respective regulatory authority. This is published as a part of AIP(Aeronautical Information Publication).

This [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Information_Publication) contains links to some of the sites having electronic AIPs. The relevant data can be found in Part 2- Enroute(ENR). For example, [this](http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadbasic/eais-2C49EA3CFCE624721786D2DB28A07346/3QDXTD5E6YWTY/EN/2015-08-20-AIRAC/html/index-ead-en-GB.html?target=eAIP/EG-GEN-0.1-en-GB.html) gives the details for UK airways.

I don't think there is a worldwide list as the airways of each country is controlled by the respective government through regulatory body and this information is updated periodically (in cycles of 28 or 56 days).

Answer (score 4):

If it's not for real-world use, navigraph.com publishes a regular database of  worldwide airways, navaids, airports, SIDs and STARS, etc.